# How do I get a row data selecting a singles cell on kendo UI MVC grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid to represent an year plan where I have a line for every person and a column with the name of the employee and another 30/31 for the day of the month shown on the grid. 
What I need is by selecting one cell, getting the employee Name (or ID) and the index.

this is the gird code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WorkTimeManager.Presentation.Models.YearPlanViewModel>()
      .Name("gridJan")

      .Columns(col =>
      {
          col.Bound(c => c.EmployeeName).Title("Employee").Width(170);
          col.Group(group => group
           .Title("January")
           .Columns(columns =>
           {
               columns.Bound(c => c.Day1).Width(30);}
               columns.Bound(c => c.Day2).Width(30);}
               columns.Bound(c => c.Day3).Width(30);}
```

...and some more...
the grid is selectable by cell (NOT row)

```
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
```

and I need to acess the data item with JavaScript, so far this is all I got:

```
function getDataFromGrid(gridName){
        var grid = $('#'+gridName).data('kendoGrid');
        alert(grid);
        var cell = grid.select();
```

using

```
var data = grid.dataItem(cell);
```

won't work unless is selectable by row (not cell).

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pizzy Could you use jQuery and a click event to navigate the grid? Something similar to below..

```
$('#gridJan tr td').click(function(){  

   //Get the name, etc by navigating upward from td to the tr parent and then back down to find specific child td that contains the needed data
   var id = $(this).parent('tr').children('whatever you are looking for').html();

   ...
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for something that would give me the item from the dataSource and not the html produced but with this I found a away to get the Employee Name text on the td and I think I can work with that.

Comment: @Pizzy glad I could help. I think the issue is you've already completely rendered the table by the time they click on the cell. I'm not familiar with Kendo but maybe they have something in their library that allows for ajax on click of cell or something.

Comment: I had to make some changes but you pointed me to another way of thinking and that helped a lot! Telerik's kendo UI lets me get the object form the dataSource when selecting a row but I couldn't find anything from a single cell. Thank you for your help

what I did:

    function getEmployeeFromGrid(){
        var grid = $('gridJan").data('kendoGrid');
        var cell = grid.select();
            var employeeName = $(cell).parent('tr').children('td').html();
            return JSON.stringify(employeeName);
 }

Answer (score 1):

GridSelectionMode is "Multiple" and the GridSelectionType is "Cell" the select method return array of selected grid cells

```
var grid = $("#gridJan").data("kendoGrid");
currentSelection = grid.select();
selectedRows = [];
currentSelection.each(function () {
var currentRowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
if (selectedRows.indexOf(currentRowIndex) == -1) {
    selectedRows.push(currentRowIndex);
}
})
```

Comment: this solves the other part of my problem, multiple selection! What I need was multiple selection on the same row, changed "tr" to "td" and it worked as expected